# Business Central Sandbox for old version

Tags: sandbox, dynamics-business-central

How can I create / access a Sandbox on the cloud for an old version of Business Central, preferably version 14 but I'll take anything close to that? My dev PC doesn't have the resources to run Docker or Hyper-V. For instance, can it be done on the Dynamics 365 Business Central admin center?

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft does not offer sandboxes for these old versions because they are not offered as cloud versions. They don't even offer new sandboxes for the previous major version when a new major version is released.